# Laravel-Websocket closed before connection is established

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am developing a laravel application in which real-time data is to be extracted using laravel-WebSockets package.I have seen people having issues at production side but this is on development side. I am accessing web-app using host-entry

All initial steps completed( downloading laravel-WebSocket package, pusher-js, php-pusher-server)

And executed `php artisan websockets:serve`. When I refreshed browser I am getting error in console
`app.js:40145 WebSocket connection to 'wss://erweb.in.linuxense.com:6001/app/erkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.3&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. app.js:42637 WebSocket connection to 'wss://erweb.in.linuxense.com:6001/app/erkey?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.3&flash=false' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out`

**Things checked**

1. Port 6001 is open & listening. Verified using netstat -tulpn
2. Echo config -
   `window.Echo = new Echo({ broadcaster: 'pusher', key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY, forceTLS: true, wsHost: window.location.hostname, encrypted: false, wsPort: 6001, wssPort: 6001, disableStats: true, enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'] });`
3. In broadcasting.php
   `

   'pusher' => [
   'driver' => 'pusher',
   'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
   'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
   'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
   'options' => [
   'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
   'useTLS' => true,
   'host' => '127.0.0.1',
   'port' => 6001,
   'scheme' => 'http',
   'encrypted' => false,
   ],
   ],

`
4. No changes made to SSL part of websocket config file

Comment: have you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, i got it to work. First and foremost thing is to downgrade your pusher from 6.* to 4.*. There is some issue with that. Here is the config inside resources/js/bootstrap.js 
   window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6002,
    wssPort: 6002,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});Whenever you make change with bootstrap.js file, make sure to run _npm run dev_ / _npm run production_ . Also add **verify_peer=>false** in ssl array inside config/websockets.php

Comment: @BilalArshad Check out the comment, tell me if it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got it to work. The first and foremost thing is to downgrade your pusher from `6.*` to `4.*`.

There is some issue with that. Here is the config inside

```
resources/js/bootstrap.js
 window.Echo = new Echo({ broadcaster: 'pusher', key: 
 process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY, 
 wsHost: window.location.hostname, 
 wsPort: 6002, 
 wssPort: 6002, 
 disableStats: true, 
 enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
 });
```

Whenever you make a change with the bootstrap.js file, make sure to `

run npm run dev`/`npm run production`.

Also add `verify_peer=>false` in ssl array inside `config/websockets.php`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error but when I changed the pusher version to "pusher-js": "^4.3.1" in package.json the issue was resolved